# how can i evaluate StratifiedKFold model

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

```
    import numpy as np
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense
    from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier 
    from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold 
    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict   

    x_train = dataset[0:700,:-1]
    y_train = dataset[0:700,-1]
    x_test = dataset[700:,:-1]
    y_test = dataset[700:,-1]

    def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

    model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=100, batch_size=64)
    skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=seed) 

    scores = cross_val_score(model, x_train, y_train, cv=skf)
    predictions = cross_val_predict(model, x_test, y_test, cv=skf)
```

I want to train [x_train], [y_train] by StratifiedKFold
and eveluate by [x_test], [y_test] 
how can i do?
I tried cross_val_predict. but i think it is not appropriate.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to split train and test in a stratified way?

Comment: yes exactly right . i want to split train and test in a stratified way. train(x_train, y_train) and test(x_test, y_test)

Answer (score 0):

To split between train and test in a stratified way you can use:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
dataset_train, dataset_test = train_test_split(dataset,
                                                stratify=dataset[:,-1], 
                                                test_size=0.2)

#split both datasets into X,y
```

Check:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

[Stratified Train/Test-split in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29438265/stratified-train-test-split-in-scikit-learn)

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
accuracy=[]
for train in skf.split(x_train, y_train):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

how about this one? it is work but i don`t know is it correct.

Comment: Why are you loop 3 times, creative a new model on each occasion (with overwriting) while not making use of the iterating variable `train` inside the loop?