# Trying to split my datafame into a representative train and test set

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have some data set. I want to split it into a train and test set. The train set is to hold 2/3 of the data. I want the two sets to be representative of the whole set. In my "Class" column I have either 4 or 2 to represent two classes. I want my test set to have the same ratio of 4:2. In order to do this I created this snippet of code:

```
trainTotal = 455
benTotal = 296
malTotal = 455-296
b = 0
m = 0
tr = 0
i = 0
j = 0

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    if row['Class'] == 2:
        if tr < trainTotal and b < benTotal:
            train.loc[i] = data.iloc[index]
            b = b+1
            tr = tr + 1
            i = i+1
        else:
            test.loc[j] = data.iloc[index]
            j = j+1
    if row['Class'] == 4:
        if tr < trainTotal and m < malTotal:
            train.loc[i] = data.iloc[index]
            tr = tr + 1            
            i = i + 1
            m = m+1
        else:
            test.loc[j] = data.iloc[index]
            j = j + 1
```

I am getting the correct toal number of values inside my train dataframe, but the cases are not represented as I had hoped. It is entering into `if tr < trainTotal and b < benTotal:` too many times. Any idea what the issue may be?

Comment: Why not use sklearn train_test_split?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29438265/stratified-train-test-split-in-scikit-learn

Comment: Is it entering more than 296 times?

Comment: I thought if I use train_test_split it will just split the data how I specify. I was worried that the data would not be representative of the class column the way I want it to be

Comment: Yes it is and I have no idea why it would @cosmic_inquiry

Comment: @newwebdev22 Read the link I provided.  Plenty of options to stratify your data.

Comment: Is `train` empty to start with?

Comment: Yes it only has column names. I checked the size before trying to add things to it

Comment: I used the `train_test_split` from `sklearn` as @MichaelGardner suggested, and to make sure it splits the class evenly, I put it into a `for` loop of let's say `i in range(30)`, used the `i` as the `random_state` parameter, printed the classes ratio for each `i`, and then chose the `random_state` who gave the closest ratio to the complete data ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Michael Gardner said, `train_test_split`is the function you're looking for.

By default it'll split randomly, but you can use `stratify` to tell it that you want the same ratio for your Class column in the train and test datasets.

It works like this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    data,
    target,
    test_size = 0.3,
    stratify=data[['your_column']]
)
```