# Weighted train, test, validation split for image classification

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, deep-learning

[image: Dataframe Image]
I am trying to split the above dataframe into train (80%), validation (10%), and test (10%); however, I want to maintain almost equal number of diseases in each set. The Finding_Labels column has the list of diseases an image is linked to.

Each image may be linked to more than one disease, as seen in the first row – this is a little problematic. Therefore, how can I split this in a manner where the 3 sets have almost equal number of disease?

An answer in PyTorch would be appreciated.

Name of disease and count:

```
{'Atelectasis': 391,
         'Infiltration': 1181,
         'No Finding': 3479,
         'Emphysema': 116,
         'Pneumonia': 116,
         'Pleural_Thickening': 130,
         'Pneumothorax': 361,
         'Mass': 241,
         'Nodule': 190,
         'Consolidation': 299,
         'Edema': 124,
         'Cardiomegaly': 157,
         'Effusion': 506,
         'Fibrosis': 25,
         'Hernia': 1}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use `PyTorch` to split your data? I would use the splitting method of [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html). You can use the argument `stratify` to maintain an equal label ratio between testing and training data.

Comment: @ko3 no, actually. My team uses PyTorch so I said that. However, how will I use stratify here?

Comment: If you are allowed and willing to use `sklearn`, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29438265/stratified-train-test-split-in-scikit-learn#:~:text=As%20such%2C%20it%20is%20desirable%20to%20split%20the,to%20the%20y%20component%20of%20the%20original%20dataset.) post.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, I would use `sklearn` to solve your problem.

Suppose, for instance, you have the following feature and label data sets, where the number of one attributes `(y==1).sum()` equals the number of zero attributes `(y==0).sum()` (so you have a one-to-zero ratio of `1.0`):

```py
from sklearn import datasets

X, y = datasets.make_blobs(n_samples=10000, centers=2, random_state=0)

print(np.bincount(y)[0]/np.bincount(y)[1]) # 1.0
```

Then, you can split your data into training, validation and testing data while maintaining the same attribute-ratio like this:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, random_state=42, test_size=0.2)
X_val, X_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(X_test, y_test, stratify=y_test, random_state=42, test_size=0.5)

print(np.bincount(y_train)[0]/np.bincount(y_train)[1]) # 1.0
print(np.bincount(y_test)[0]/np.bincount(y_test)[1])   # 1.0
print(np.bincount(y_val)[0]/np.bincount(y_val)[1])     # 1.0
print(len(y_train), len(y_val), len(y_test))           # 8000, 1000, 1000
```

Comment: However, if you see the dataset, each image has multiple labels. So then I can't use a binary ratio, like you showed. Do you know how I can do this for multi-lable classification? It would be best if you can show an example using my dataset.

Comment: @Shloakr, the label 'Hernia' only occurs one time.. Therefore, it cannot be stratified. Can you cluster your labels? Or collect more data?

Comment: I can cluster it with any other label. It shouldn't matter.